# Background Image In Aspx Content Page Won't Change On Page Load

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have searched and searched for an answer to this across the web, yet I have not found a "clearly stated" answer as to why this is happening. And I have re-worked to no avail.

1. I have a Asp.Net site, with a "Master Page" and few "Content" pages
2. There is a CSS file which successfully assigns a "background-image" in the body - for all the pages:

   `body { background-image: url('../Images/TestImage1.jpg'); }`
3. I have another image, say ***TestImage2.jpg***, which sits in same Images folder in the solution, and I want to display this image on a specific "Content Page" when that page loads. Yet, it is not loading on the page, and background just turns white without any image at all - here's my code:

My MasterPage has the correct items for `runat="server"`:

```
<head runat="server"> 
<title></title>    
<link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

... and also...

```
<body runat="server">
<form style="height: 906px" runat="server">
```

Now, here's my code-behind for the content page I wish to have new image appear on Page_Load:

```
using System;
using System.Text; 
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class TechCall : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder script = new StringBuilder();
    script.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
    script.Append("document.body.style.background = \"url('../Images/CPUBack2nd.jpg')\";");
    script.Append("document.body.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';");
    script.Append("</script>");

    this.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "changeBackground", script.ToString());
}    
}
```

***CPUBack2nd.jpg*** is the actual of name of the image in place of ***TestImage2.jpg***, but as far as I can see, I am using the correct path for the image, as like the one in the CSS file which defines the default background image. Yet, when the page loads, no image at all appears for the background - just a white space, and original image appears on other pages correctly.

Can someone examine and tell me what I am missing here? Note: please don't suggest JQuery, as if it can be solved using Javascript, then I wish to stick with this usage, as I just want to learn to make it work with JS.

Comment: Does the code behind file live int root folder?

Comment: I have just tried your code and it works fine on a simple page I created. Did you check the CSS with the browser's developer tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much wrangling, moving some things around and isolating them in the CSS style sheet to clean up the Master page, where I had some stray CSS classes, AND of course building on the "hunch" provided by **Jon P** on possible root relative with Javascript, here's what did it:

Instead of using this:

```
script.Append("document.body.style.background = \"url('../Images/TestImage1.jpg')\";");
```

The answer was to use this:

```
script.Append("document.body.style.background = \"url('/MyProjectName/Images/TestImage2.jpg')\";");
```

So, I don't know why I had go all the around the world it seems to figure that out, but I guess that's how it is with programming... the difference ALWAYS lies in the LITTLE THINGS!

Thanks to all who contributed to getting me to think about what was going on here! Hence, the lesson is also THIS CAN BE DONE WITH JAVASCRIPT. :)

Comment: Yes, but the question remains as to why use javascript when you can use CSS? Anywho, I'm glad you got it working.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest not using javascript at all. You should have a handy `ContentPlaceHolder` in the header section. Add the following in there to overide the default body style

```
<style type="text/style">
    body  { background-image: url('../Images/TestImage2.jpg'); }
</style>
```

As this will appear in the page after the head contents of the materpage it will overide the earlier CSS.

I would also consider using [Root Releative](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WScbb6b82af5544594822510a94ae8d65-7c44a.html) paths particularly on master pages as it makes the releative location of the calling document and the called resource irrelevant. In which case change the above to:

```
<style type="text/style">
    body  { background-image: url('/Images/TestImage2.jpg'); }
</style>
```

Assuming that the `Images` directory resides at the root level of your document.

If you really want to persist with javascript. Check the path or use Root Relative. Remember that the path is relevant to the document calling the resorce. So just because a path works in a CSS file does not mean it will work in a page which sits at a diferent level of the website. Use a CSS debug tool Like FireBug for Firefox (a free download) or Developer Tools in Chrome (in built) to check if the image was at the expected location.